# Is there some way to specify a "not" type in flow?

Tags: flowtype

Is there some way to specify a "not" type in flow? For example, 

`compact = (input: Array<any>): Array<notFalsey> => input.filter(i => !!i);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no syntax to specify a "not" type, like `$Not<string>`, which would be anything but a string.

For your specific `compact` example, Flow's library definition for `Array.prototype.filter` does include a special case for using the `Boolean` function as the filter function. So you can write

```
const compactedArray = myArray.filter(Boolean);
```

v0.31.0 will ship with a magic type `$NonMaybeType`, so you will be able to write a `compact` function with return type `Array<$NonMaybeType<T>>`.